# How to get access to facebook user graph

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have to build a simple facebook app which will display the user name on a vday card.

I have it working for my account (the dev account I am using) but it won't work with anyone else who goes to the app. I think I am missing some sort of permission step? I really have no idea how to fix this any help would be greatly appreciated. (the link = https://apps.facebook.com/webapps_vdaycard/)

```
<?php

require_once('fb-php-sdk/src/facebook.php');

$config = array(
'appId' => 'Numbers',
'secret' => 'Numbers'
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$id = '/'.$user;
if ($user){
$user_graph = $facebook->api($id);
}
else{
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'display'=>'popup',
                    'scope' =>'name, first_name',
        'redirect_uri' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/webapps_vdaycard'
    ));
echo '<p><a href="'. $loginUrl. '" target="_top">Login to this App</a></p>';

}

$name = $user_graph['name'];
?>



            <main>
        <img src="./images/hearts.svg" class="heart" alt="love hearts">
        <div class="info">
            <h1>Happy Valentine's Day</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><strong>To: </strong><?php echo $name;?></li>
                <li><strong>From: </strong>Secret Admirer</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: change the scope to just email and see 'scope' =>'email', since name, first_name are public scopes and no need to pass in the login dialogue.

Comment: :) you welcome !! Posted the answer !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the scope to just email and see `'scope' =>'email',` since name, first_name are public scopes and no need to pass in the login dialogue

Check here for  more details

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions